How do deal with kubeadm init failing with rpc error: code = Unknown desc = malformed header: missing HTTP content-type?
Upon running this:
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock --v=5

I get the following error:
[kubelet-finalize] Updating "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf" to point to a rotatable kubelet client certificate and key
I0630 04:18:05.547359   69027 kubeletfinalize.go:134] [kubelet-finalize] Restarting the kubelet to enable client certificate rotation
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = malformed header: missing HTTP content-type
unable to create deployment

Standard Debian 12 install. Everything updated to the latest before starting this.
I've tried repeatedly to stop and remove/reset everything with:
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop kube-proxy
systemctl stop kube-apiserver
systemctl stop kube-controller-manager
systemctl stop kube-scheduler

kill $(pgrep kube-apiserver)
kill $(pgrep kube-controller-manager)
kill $(pgrep kube-scheduler)
kill $(pgrep etcd)
kill $(pgrep kubelet)

rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/manifests/*.yaml
rm -rf /var/lib/etcd

kubeadm reset

rm -rf /etc/cni/net.d

However, I just get the same error.
If I don't clean up and run the same kubeadm init command, I get:
[ERROR Port-6443]: Port 6443 is in use
[ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use
[ERROR Port-10257]: Port 10257 is in use
[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml already exists
[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml already exists
[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml already exists
[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml already exists
[ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
[ERROR Port-2379]: Port 2379 is in use
[ERROR Port-2380]: Port 2380 is in use
[ERROR DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty

While I can fix this with running the abovementioned cleaning/reset commands, I will just encounter the:
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = malformed header: missing HTTP content-type

error when I then again run kubeadm init.
Not sure where to go from here, this should be pretty straightforward.
